# Ubuntu One Eating My Dropbox

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-one, dropbox

I used to have a perfectly good working DropBox account on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS computer. Somewhere along the chain of "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade" over the past year, my DropBox suddenly stopped working. Instead, I see Ubuntu One stuff on the menus in Nautilus instead of DropBox.

So, I did "apt-get --purge remove nautilus-dropbox", and then went to DropBox.com to download the deb file and reinstall it again.

But no dice. I get the DropBox icon in my "systray", and clicking it opens ~/Dropbox folder, but it does not sync with DropBox and rightclicking Nautilus does not show me menu items for Dropbox. Instead, I see items for Ubuntu One sharing.

I like Ubuntu One really only for the music purchasing because I am guessing that it helps Canonical.com pay Ubuntu's light bills. But I'm not interested in anything else with Ubuntu One besides that -- not interested in Ubuntu One offsite file storage. I really just want my Dropbox sync with Nautilus to start working again.

How do I fix this back so that Dropbox syncs with Nautilus again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to issue a `dropbox start` or possibly a `dropbox start -i`, it seems as though your daemon is not running.

It will automatically do everything for you, and nautilus extension will be enabled once the daemon starts.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up giving up on Ubuntu One, thinking it was conflicting with Dropbox APIs. I did "sudo apt-cache search ubuntu | grep -i one" and found I could remove Ubuntu One with "sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-client". I also stopped any Ubuntu One services left behind. I rebooted the PC, and then waited for the folder to synchronize. All was well after that, and the DropBox menu appeared again when I rightclick a folder in ~/Dropbox.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure exactly what you're seeing, here; we don't do anything that would interfere with Dropbox in any way.